# What branch do I update an applications version number?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-flow

My app requires changing the version number in a configuration file.
If I am following the GIT Flow way of branching, what branch should I ideally be changing this file?
Is it develop right before we create the release branch, or is it in the release branch (which then later gets updated back into develop)?

Comment: Don't.  Do *not* store version numbers in files in the repo at all. Instead, derive the version number from tags (preferably signed).  Then the question is moot.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with storing version numbers in the files?

Comment: if you store version numbers in files you run into the problem you have in this question, among other issues.  There should be exactly one canonical source of the version, and that should be the VCS.  If you put a version in a file, then make 3 commits to the repositoy, you now have 3 different versions of the software that all have exactly the same version number, and they cannot be easily distinguished.

Comment: @WilliamPursell But how do you deal with dependencies in the project then? For example angular libraries have their version number, which we can omit in our code. But the package.json contains dependencies to `@angular/core` `@angular/common` etc, with their version number. These must be specified in the code

Comment: Pieterjan If you need to have your project's version number specified in a file, then you need to autogenerate that file.  Having multiple versions of your project that have the same version of a dependency is not an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it on the release branch because if you use Git Flow, it means that you have a test process before your release and therefore possibly multiple release candidates.

As an example, let's say your product is at version `1.0.0` and you want to release version `1.0.1`. You cut a branch `release-1.0.1` from `develop` and change the version on the release branch to `1.0.1-pre1`. That's your first release candidate. You run your tests and find a bug that blocks the release. You fix this bug in the release branch. Now you have another release candidate with the version `1.0.1-pre2`. You test this new release candidate again, find another bug, and fix it as well. You now have a third release candidate `1.0.1-pre3`. It passes the tests and becomes the official release. Now you can change the version number to `1.0.1`, release, and merge back into `develop`. You have a clear history of your three release candidates.

If you for some reason decide to stop the release, for example because while testing you realize a new feature isn't ready for release yet and needs more work, you can simply delete the `release-1.0.1` branch. On `develop` the version is still `1.0.0`. You can release `1.0.1` with a new release branch later.

Comment: This is great and all makes sense.

Comment: But this would mean that the `master` branch, with the project's dependencies, never gets updated. So the `@angular/core` `@angular/common` versions on the master branch will never change to newer versions...

Comment: In Git Flow (https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model) the master branch would get updated separately after a successful release. Please also note that updating dependencies should happen in a separate commit before the release. You want to test your application's behavior using the new dependencies for a while before releasing a new version that depends on them into the wild.